# For " Follow active quads" method, do I need to make the entire object active or just the outside face?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have modeled this coffee cup.  I used materials and different colors to make different faces. When completed I plan on exporting it to second life as a 3D object.  I marked seams and unwrapped it. The "island" with the arrow is the brown outside face of the cup.  I need some experienced advise on how to unwrap this cup so it will properly take a texture.  If I use the "Follow active quads method", do I need to use it to unwrap the entire cup, all at once?   Should I try to unwrap island by island?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Follow Active Quads* on any selection you want.
I doesn't have to be the whole mesh.

*Example of unwrapping a part of mesh using Follow Active Quads.*

[image]